# How to position one end of a line element dynamically based on date?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm not sure if my title is accurate, so let me describe the issue I am trying to solve. First, here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epLg0es9/15/)

If the user option/alt-drags the blue circle, they are able to move the "event box" – which is a `group` composed of a `rect`, `circle` `text` element and `line`. In the example shown in the image below, the `x2/y2` end point of the line should be fixed to its timeline date. For example, the red line for "January 1 2003" should always point to that date even when the "event box" is repositioned.

I know how to make the line point straight down to the date – but when the "event box" is moved, it would no longer points to the correct date. I am using two date properties:

1. actualDate - which is used (wrongly) to determine the line endpoint
2. positionDate - which is updated as the user repositions the "event box"

This is the code positioning the line.

```
      d3.select(this).select("line.leaderLine")
          .attr("x1", horizontal_margin)
          .attr("y1", 0)
          .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
                return x(new Date(d.actualDate));
           })
          .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
                return cV - d.yPos;
            });
```

Any help or tips much appreciated – I've been struggling with this for a while.

---

[image]

---

```
var horizontal_margin = 10;
var vertical_margin = 10;
var spacer = 10;
var svgWidth = 700 - (horizontal_margin * 2)
var svgHeight = 500 - (vertical_margin * 2);

var margin_content = {
    top: vertical_margin,
    right: svgWidth - horizontal_margin,
    bottom: svgHeight - 20,
    left: horizontal_margin
};
var margin_scrubber = {
    top: margin_content.bottom + spacer,
    right: horizontal_margin,
    bottom: svgHeight - spacer,
    left: horizontal_margin
};
var tlWidth = margin_content.right - margin_content.left;
var tlHeight = margin_content.bottom - margin_content.top;
var cV = (margin_content.bottom - margin_content.top) / 2;
var svg;
var x;
var x2;
var xAxis_focus;
var xAxis_scrubber;
var zoom;
var content;
var scrubber;
var brush;

// transform used for dragging & zooming
// var zoomTrans = d3.zoomIdentity;

var drag_this = d3.drag().subject(this)
    .on('start', function (d) {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.altKey == true) {
            if (d.x1) {
                d.x1 = d3.event.x - d.xt;
                d.y1 = d3.event.y - d.yt;
            } else {
                d.x1 = d3.event.x;
                d.y1 = d3.event.y;
            }
        }
    })
    .on('drag', function (d) {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.altKey == true) {

            d3.select(this)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.x) + "," + (d3.event.y) + ")");

            d.xt = d3.event.x - d.x1;
            d.yt = d3.event.y - d.y1;
            d.yPos = d3.event.y;
            d.positionDate = x.invert(d3.event.x);

            d3.select(this).select("line.leaderLine")
                .attr("x1", horizontal_margin)
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
                    return x(new Date(d.actualDate));
                })
                .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
                    return cV - d.yPos;
                });
        }
    });


var eventData = {
    "events": [
        {
            "actualDate": "January 1 2002",
            "positionDate": 0,
            "eventText": "This is the first event",
            "xOffset": 0,
            "yPos": 80,
            "state": true
        },
        {
            "actualDate": "January 1 2003",
            "positionDate": 0,
            "eventText": "Another event",
            "xOffset": 0,
            "yPos": 300,
            "state": true
        }
    ]
};

loadTimeline(eventData);

function loadTimeline(data) {

    for (let index = 0; index < data.events.length; ++index) {
        let e = data.events[index];

        if (e.positionDate == 0) {
            e.positionDate = new Date(e.actualDate)

        } else {
            e.positionDate = new Date(e.positionDate)
        }
    }

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr('width', svgWidth)
        .attr('height', svgHeight)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_content.left + "," + margin_content.top + ")");

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%B %d %Y");

    x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, tlWidth - (horizontal_margin * 2)]);
    x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, tlWidth - (horizontal_margin * 2)]);

    xAxis_focus = d3.axisBottom(x);
    xAxis_scrubber = d3.axisBottom(x2);

    zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
        .translateExtent([
            [0, 0],
            [tlWidth - (horizontal_margin * 4), tlHeight]
        ])
        .extent([
            [0, 0],
            [tlWidth - (horizontal_margin * 4), tlHeight]
        ])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", margin_content.right - margin_content.left)
        .attr("height", margin_content.bottom - margin_content.top);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "zoom")
        .attr("width", margin_content.right - margin_content.left)
        .attr("height", margin_content.bottom - margin_content.top)
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_content.left + "," + margin_content.top + ")")
        .call(zoom)
        .on("dblclick.zoom", null);

    content = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "content")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_content.left + "," + margin_content.top + ")");

    scrubber = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "scrubber")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_scrubber.left + "," + margin_scrubber.top + ")");

    brush = d3.brushX()
        .extent([
            [0, 0],
            [tlWidth, 40]
        ])
        .on("brush end", brushed);



    var maxDate = d3.max(data.events, function (d) {
        return d.positionDate;
    })
    var newDate = new Date(maxDate.getTime());
    newDate.setYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 2);
    var pad = {
        positionDate: newDate,
        eventText: "pad"
    }
    data.events.push(pad)

    x.domain(d3.extent(data.events, function (d, i) {
        return d.positionDate;
    }));

    x2.domain(x.domain());

    // **** event
    var events = content.selectAll("g").data(data.events.filter(function (d, i) {
        if (d.state == undefined) {
            d.state = true;
        }
        return i < data.events.length - 1
    }));

    var newEvent = events.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "event")
        .call(drag_this);

    newEvent.append("line")
        .attr("class", "leaderLine")
        .attr("x1", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
            return cV - d.yPos;
        });

    newEvent.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "event-content")
        .attr("x", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("y", 15)
        .attr("width", 160)
        .attr("height", 120);

    newEvent.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "event-circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("cx", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .on("click", eventClick);

    newEvent.append("text")
        .attr('y', 5)
        .attr("x", horizontal_margin + 15)
        .attr("class", "event-text")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.actualDate;
        });


    //*** end event


    content.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_content.left + "," + cV + ")")
        .call(xAxis_focus);

    // scrubber
    scrubber.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_scrubber.left + "," + (margin_scrubber.bottom - margin_scrubber.top) / 2 + ")")
        .call(xAxis_scrubber);

    scrubber.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin_scrubber.left + "," + 0 + ")")
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, x.range());

    scrubber.append("g")
        .selectAll("rect.event-marker").data(data.events.filter(function (d, i) {
            return i < data.events.length - 1;
        }))
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "event-marker")
        .attr("x", function (d, i) {
            return x2(d.positionDate) + (margin_scrubber.left);
        })
        .attr("y", function (d, i) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                return 5
            } else {
                return 20
            }
        })
        .attr("width", 5)
        .attr("height", 5);
}


var staggerLayout = function (i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        return 20
    } else {
        return 100
    }
};


function brushed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "zoom") return; // ignore brush-by-zoom

    console.log('brushed');

    var s = d3.event.selection || x2.range();
    x.domain(s.map(x2.invert, x2));

    content.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis_focus);
    svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
        .scale(tlWidth / (s[1] - s[0]))
        .translate(-s[0], 0));


    var events = content.selectAll("g.event")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            if (d.yPos == 0) {
                d.yPos = staggerLayout(i);
            }
            return "translate(" + x(d.positionDate) + margin_content.left + "," + d.yPos + ")"
        });

    var leaderLines = content.selectAll("line.leaderLine")
        .attr("x1", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
            return x(new Date(d.actualDate));
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
            return cV - d.yPos;
            // return  (margin_content.bottom - margin_content.top) / 2;
        });
}

function zoomed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; // ignore zoom-by-brush

    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());

    content.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis_focus);
    scrubber.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));

    var events = content.selectAll("g.event")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            if (d.yPos == 0) {
                d.yPos = staggerLayout(i);
            }
            return "translate(" + x(d.positionDate) + margin_content.left + "," + d.yPos + ")"
        });

    var leaderLines = content.selectAll("line.leaderLine")
        .attr("x1", horizontal_margin)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
            return x(new Date(d.actualDate));
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
            return cV - d.yPos;
        });
}

function eventClick(d, i) {
    if (d3.event.altKey == false) {
        console.log('d', i);

        if (d.state == false) {
            d3.select(this)
                .classed("event-box", false)
                .classed("event-box-hilite", true);
            d.state = true;
            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .selectAll('.event-content')
                .style("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            d3.select(this)
                .classed("event-box", true)
                .classed("event-box-hilite", false);
            d.state = false;
            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .selectAll('.event-content')
                .style("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is how to position an element of a group relative to dynamic variables in "global", non-group coordinates.

There must be a better, less 'hacky' way to do this – but I don't know what it is. The approach below:

1. assumes the "leader lines" are not part of the "event box" groups
2. stores the needed variables (of group position) in a temporary array
3. applies those values to the "leader lines: in a `selectAll` loop.

Not pretty but it works

---

```
function zoomed() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return; 

    var t = d3.event.transform;
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());

    content.select(".axis--x").call(xAxis_focus);
    scrubber.select(".brush").call(brush.move, x.range().map(t.invertX, t));

    var tmp = [];

    var events = content.selectAll("g.event")
        .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
            if (d.yPos == 0) {
                d.yPos = staggerLayout(i);
            }

            tmp.push([x(d.positionDate) + margin_content.left, d.yPos])
            return "translate(" + x(d.positionDate) + margin_content.left + "," + d.yPos + ")"
        });

    var lines = content.selectAll("line.leader")
        .attr("x1", function (d, i) {
            return horizontal_margin + x(new Date(d.actualDate));

        })
        .attr("y1", cV)
        .attr("x2", function (d, i) {
            return tmp[i][0]
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
            return tmp[i][1]
        });

}
```